# Open graph tag HTML not working in Whatsapp, when I share my Url

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

Hello there why link url on my website does't show preview or thumbnail when I share the link in Whatsapp, but working find in Facebook, I had check the url in Open graph debuger and everything what I write in open graph tag is readly , this is my code :

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->config->item('appapi') . "/" . $newslist[0]->n_image_tny; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="<?php echo $this->config->item('appapi') . "/" . $newslist[0]->n_image_tny; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $uris; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $newslist[0]->n_content_short; ?>" />
```

and this is my example link:
[Link example](http://kuyou.id/homepage/read/4533/Intip+kesibukan+Tsamara+Amany+di+New+York)

Anyone can explain or help me, thanks be fore

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Have you been able to solve it? 
Edit: i just checked your link, and it works. Could you share your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the link direct to images as urls. For example:

```
<!-- Open Graph -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://periferia.app">
<meta property="og:title" content="My site from periferias">
<meta property="og:description" content="To read about slang.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://periferia.app/assets/images/slang.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Come to join us!">
```